# IUnity Container RegisterTypeforNavigation is not working in Prism 7

Tags: c#, .net, prism

I am having this problem when I installed prism 7

> SCS1929    'IUnityContainer' does not contain a definition for 'RegisterTypeForNavigation' and the best extension method overload 'UnityExtensions.RegisterTypeForNavigation(IUnityContainer, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IUnityContainer'

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to be the result of you only partially updating your code. Due to a number of changes particularly with Unity, Prism 7 decoupled its API from any specific container. As a result, the extensions for RegisterTypeForNavigation no longer exist for the IUnityContainer, but instead for the new IContainerRegistry. When registering your Services and Views in Prism 7, you would do this in `RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)`.

This actually provides a number of benefits including the fact that the documentation remains consistent for Prism users regardless of which container you're using. While you have not directly asked this question yet, I should mention that you should pay particular attention to how you are referencing Unity. The new maintainer for Unity changed a lot about the container which was a major break for users going from older versions of Prism to Prism 7 where we adopted the updated version of Unity. This included namespace breaks, as well as a complete change in the dependent package. If you are directly referencing the Unity Container please be sure to uninstall it and only reference the package that Prism does.